How can I read an image file and return it to the frontend client for display in the browser with C# in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project
From an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project, I am trying to return an image as a filestream t the frontend client to display in the browser.
I have written the following code
 using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filepath)) { return new FileStream(stream, contentType); }
But I have the following error message

'ControllerBase.File(byte[], string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Please how can I resolve this error?
I was expecting the File.OpenRead method to read the file to a stream when I supply the path to the file but this does not seem to be working out

Try this. It will give you a file stream that you can return directly with the File method.
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filepath))
{
    return File(stream, contentType);
}


Thank you @MalshanR. However, this method gives the following error: "Cannot access a closed file."
